# Convert Varchar with timezone to Timestamp in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a problem converting varchar to DateTime/timestamp.
Here is the case

```
ID    EVENT_TIME(Varchar)
1    2020-04-12T09:25:53+0800
2    2020-04-12T09:25:53+0700
3    2020-04-12T09:25:53+0900
```

return I want, all timestamp convert to +0700

```
ID    EVENT_TIME(Datetime)
1    2020-04-12 10:25:53 
2    2020-04-12 09:25:53
3    2020-04-12 11:25:53
```

is this possible? and how can I do it using oracle?

thanks

Comment: Why are you storing the value as a string - why isn't your column defined as timestamp (with [local] time zone)?

Answer (score 2):

Please use below query to convert varchar to timestamp using `to_timestamp_tz` and again convert it to the required time format using `to_char`

```
select ID, to_char(to_timestamp_tz(EVENT_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as event_date from table_name;
```

Example:

```
select to_char(to_timestamp_tz('2020-04-12T09:25:53+0800', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as event_date from dual;
```

[image]

Comment: what about the convert of timezone? I mean the +0700

Comment: For all the records you want to convert with `+0700`?

Comment: yes correct, I need all the record convert to +0700

Comment: Can you also post the expected result in the question?

Comment: as you can see in my expected result before, the hours are changing +1 hours if there is +0800 and +2 hours if there is data with +0900

Answer (score 0):

As @Jim said, you can use `to_timestamp_tz()` with a character literal to convert the string to a timestamp value:

```
to_timestamp_tz(event_time, 'SYYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM')
```

The to normalise to the +07:00 offset you can use `at time zone`:

```
to_timestamp_tz(event_time, 'SYYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') at time zone '+07:00'
```

If you don't want to keep the time zone part you can cast to a plain timestamp:

```
cast(
  to_timestamp_tz(event_time, 'SYYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') at time zone '+07:00'
  as timestamp)
```

Or you can `cast (... as date)` as you don't have fractional seconds.

Or you can convert that back to a string for display:

```
to_char(
  to_timestamp_tz(event_time, 'SYYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') at time zone '+07:00',
  'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f94004dc4c7cc7bb94718868a74f8bbb)

Comment: Thanks Alex, I just found the answer, that I only need to change it based on the place. So I use this `cast(to_timestamp_tz(event_time, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:sstzhtzm') at time zone 'Asia/Jakarta' as date)`

Comment: Using regions is safer, for both the original string and the conversion - I just stuck with the offsets you showed. And yes, casting to date instead of timestamp is fine as you don't have fractional seconds.